# Any reason why the values ​contained in the EditText are not being transferred to the variables?

Tags: android, kotlin

**The following function takes the values ​​of the EditText and assigns them to variables, then these values ​​are concatenated and stored in the variable var_LineaVet which is a String.

this is stored in a text file, but instead of having something like

```
1;Mary;Pet Planet;6 to 8;3012025;Av. 25 PB5. La Quintana;maryvet@gmail.com;@maryvet;
```

but the reality is that it is saving the following

```
ompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{1da18551 VFED..CL ........ 149,295-494,354 #7f080029 app:id/VetNombre};androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{20aa1b6 VFED..CL ........ 149,364-494,423 #7f080025 app:id/VetClinica};androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{24907eb7 VFED..CL ........ 149,433-494,492 #7f080028 app:id/VetHorario};androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{10abe624 VFED..CL ........ 149,500-494,559 #7f08002b app:id/VetTelefono};androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{1d28258d VFED..CL ........ 149,568-494,627 #7f080026 app:id/VetDireccion};androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{3d972342 VFED..CL ........ 149,637-494,696 #7f080027 app:id/VetEmail};androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{d244f53 VFED..CL .F...... 149,702-494,761 #7f08002a app:id/VetSociales};
```

The following code corresponds to the function that the process performs.

```
fun inc_Vet(view: View) {
    ResetVarVet()
    var_dbnombrevet = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.VetNombre).toString()
    var_clinicavet = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.VetClinica).toString()
    var_horaiovet = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.VetHorario).toString()
    var_telefonovet = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.VetTelefono).toString()
    var_direccionvet = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.VetDireccion).toString()
    var_emailvet = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.VetEmail).toString()
    var_socialesvet = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.VetSociales).toString()
    registrosVet()
    try {
        val directory = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MisMascotas")
        val file = File(directory, "veterinario.txt")
        val osw = OutputStreamWriter(FileOutputStream(file))
        var_codigovet = num_RegistrosVet + 1
        osw.write(
            var_LineaVet.toString() +
            var_codigovet.toString() + ";" +
            var_dbnombrevet + ";" +
            var_clinicavet + ";" +
            var_horaiovet + ";" +
            var_telefonovet + ";" +
            var_direccionvet + ";" +
            var_emailvet + ";" +
            var_socialesvet + ";"
        )
        osw.flush()
        osw.close()
        Toast.makeText(this, "He incluido el Veterinario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        registrosVet()
        no_guardadoV = false
        } catch (e: IOException) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ha ocurrido un ERROR al momento de incluir el Veterinario",                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        no_guardadoV = true
   }
   ResetVarVet()
   ClkVet(view)
}
```

The problem is in the transfer of the values ​​stored in the EditText, since if I directly assign strings as tests to the variables that add up in the variable , then the data is saved correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value that is entered into an `EditText`, you may use the [`getText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText#getText()) function. See the following code:

```
var_dbnombrevet = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.VetNombre).getText().toString();
```

Update all occurences in your code accordingly. 
The problem with your current code is that the `toString()` function just returns the String representation of the Java object, and not the content of the `EditText`.